# Almacenar DataPicker en SQLite [xamarin]

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datepicker

Estoy en Xamarin.Forms ,no consigo almacenar la fecha de un DataPicker en la base de datos. 
Esta es la clase de la base de datos:

```
public DateTime Fecha
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string FechaModificada
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM}", Fecha);
        }
    }
```

Y esto el fragmento de código de XAML:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="HoraFinal"
                        MinimumDate="1/1/1999" 
                        MaximumDate="1/1/3000" 
                        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"
                        DateSelected="Fecha_Selected"
                        />
            <Entry Text="{Binding Fecha, Source={x:Reference HoraFinal}, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

Y en la parte de programación realicé una alerta para ver si me recoge bien la fecha.

```
//Click en hora
    DateTime ultima;
    async void Fecha_Selected(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ultima = e.NewDate;
        var fechaMostrar = e.NewDate.ToString("D");
        await DisplayAlert("DatePicker", fechaMostrar, "Aceptar");
```

La recoge bien pero luego no almacena bien la fecha en la base de datos. Almacena con el valor 01/01/0001. 
Cómo consigo recoger la fecha del DataPicker y almacenarla correctamente en la base de datos??????

Comment: Coloca el código donde guardas la fecha, así como la manera en que llamas esa función desde tu Interfaz de Usuario

Comment: Ya es lo que he puesto aquí. Sigo sin resolver el dilema de cómo recoge el dato el Datapicker. No sé si estoy haciendo bien el binding.

Comment: Me refiero al codigo que tienes para almacenarlo en SQLite, con el SaveChanges, Add, etc.